# Remove Launcher in Unity 2D?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d, docky

I like Unity but I'd rather use Docky as a launcher than the Unity Launcher. Is it possible to remove the launcher in Unity 2D or possibly preventing it from loading at start-up? Thanks

Comment: this might be for you http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/unity-2d-tweak-app-updated-for-11-10/

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in this thread: [How to autohide the Launcher in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105103/how-to-autohide-unity-2d)

Do a

```
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/hide-mode 1
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/use-strut false
```

to hide the Bar, that it now shows directly.

and use the following tool do configure that it doesnt come when moving your mouse to the right:
http://ubuntuone.com/0eyiDuvaOmAi25OlN3wcTX

Comment: We dont usually condone random binaries on this site - please can you explain what this package is, how it is created and most importantly supply the code changes you have made.

Comment: It is not mine, and I dont have any technically knowledge about this. It is from an answer of my thread, I linked above.